# Which is more efficient in PHP, explode() from a database of nested switch case

Tags: php, database, function, webserver, switch-statement

i'm programming a system which records users achievements in games by collecting Trophy data which is uploaded to the system, it got it to work fine but i have started to think about one part of the system i can do in 2 different ways

this part of the system gathers a Trophy's rank (Bronze, Silver, Gold, Crystal, Jade) and how many points it's worth, each user as a record in a game's table, each field apart from the tables primary key and the user_id foreign key represent each trophy that can be obtained in the exact order they are listed, this means they aren't sorted in any way which a machine can easily search though

how i have combat this is that there is another table which each record contains the game and a string which lists the rank order of the trophies separated by |'s so when i use explode(STRING,"|") i get an array and each index of the array is a single character, it can look something like this

b|b|s|g|c|g|s|j

that is just the trophy rank, the point value is done though function where i pass the game id and trophy id and a switch case statement will first check what game i have passed while nested switch cases in each case will check the id, in each case of these they return the point value of a trophy

naturally i didn't plan out my code, the rank string above originally didn't have the | and i didn't do the point values like that cause unlike the rank, a score value van very between 1 and 3 digits, now i know i can do the same with the point value as i did with the rank order

i want to know which method is more efficient for the web server and for browsers, pulling a string from a database and using explode(STRING,"|") (and intval() to convert the point values from strings to integers, need them like that for calculations) or calling a function with switch case statement like a look up table or if what i already have is efficient enough

i'm not really interested in trying to do what i am doing in a completely different way just to make it even more efficient as these methods perfectly fit the nested loops in which i am using them in

Comment: This is very abstract, you could improve the post by adding the table structures and maybe some of your current queries that are relevant.

Comment: This question isn't really in a state it can be properly answered. Without example data and code it's very difficult to give an informed reply.  I will say this, though.  Don't put serialized data in a database!  Doing so violates the first normal form, which states that a column in a database should hold one and only one piece of data.  By serializing you're basically stuffing multiple pieces of data into the column, and this will make your life hell later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try reconstruct your db, there could be a table achievements with a many2many relations to users,trophy tables..columns user id, a trophy id, total points and/or other data with a view you can get the username,trophy type, and points

Answer (score 0):

I think better to use [serialize PHP function](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php):

```php
public function setValues($values) {
    if (is_array($values)) {
        $this->setFieldValue('values', serialize($values)); // for db field
    } elseif (is_string($values)) {
        $this->setFieldValue('values', serialize(explode(",", $values)));  // for db field
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Invalid values data format");
    }
}

public function getValues() {
    $values = $this->getFieldValue('values'); // or something else getting field data from DB
    if ($values == "") {
        return array();
    } else {
        return unserialize($values);
    }
}
```

In this cae you have fast and easy method for store and restore data.